# how to customize instock notifier template cuz it's corrupted?

Tags: wordpress, html-email

all of the site templates is good and sent successfully

the problem is with the instock notifier templates when a user put it's email to be reminded when a stock is back
when a users subscribe to instock notifier they recive a corrupted  email the text is out of the frame just on mobile phones

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first. Then read [ask] here. After that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide a minimal reproducible example for debugging details.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.